# is possible to collected Camel route metrics at user level/user specific

Tags: apache-camel

We are building file processing system (web application + stateful) using camel, jms and rest. Multiple user can upload files. There is requirement to show min, max, mean time taken, average no of hits and etc specific to user. This almost inline with route metrics provided by camel. Is there way to collect this route metrics at user level? or should we extended metrics components and its registry to meet our needs.

Added below changes to code to collect metrics.

```
 <!--added to bean context --> 
 <bean id="policy" class="org.apache.camel.component.metrics.routepolicy.MetricsRoutePolicy"/>

 <!-- below changes done to route -->        
 <route id="prefRate"  routePolicyRef="policy">

     <from uri="cxfrs://bean://prefRateService?bindingStyle=SimpleConsumer"/>
      <log message="Processing username:${headers.username}"/>
     <setHeader headerName="HEADER_METRIC_NAME">
                <simple>${headers.username}</simple>
     </setHeader>
     <to uri="log:body?level=INFO"/>
     <to uri="bean:fxPrefRateProcessor" />
      <to uri="metrics:meter:prefRateCounter"/>
  </route>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can overwrite the name of a metric in the route by setting the `MetricsConstants.HEADER_METRIC_NAME` header.  To get a unique metric per user, just include the unique user name in the metric name.  You could do something like this:

```
.setHeader(MetricsConstants.HEADER_METRIC_NAME, simple("your.metric.name.for.user.${body.user}"))
.to("metrics:meter:your.metric.name");
```

This would give you per-user metrics.  There's some documentation on the apache site that covers the [metrics component and how to set variables/values](http://camel.apache.org/metrics-component.html)

Comment: We have done changes as per your recommendation. But unable to view metrics in hawtio.

Comment: Make sure you're populating your user name properly (the above simple expression is an example, I don't know where you keep your unique user string in your exchange), and check to make sure the right metrics are being logged in your camel logs.

Comment: Name are uniquely populated which is check via trace in hawtIO. It is my mistake. Documentation shows clearly that metrics can be pulled from Java code. Meanwhile I will also check the camel logs as per suggestion.